# Set image from rss feed as wallaper

Tags: jquery, parsing, rss, bing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Bing background image rss as background of my page jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593622/set-bing-background-image-rss-as-background-of-my-page-jquery)

I am a jquery newbie. I need to parse the first image from this RSS feed and use it as the background image for my page. I am developing a phonegap app so cross domain restriction is not an issue.

Here is the rss feed: http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages

Comment: Are you trying to have this image change dynamically?

Comment: Yes i would love to have it change dynamically

Comment: Hmmm...so you want the background to update as the rss feed updates?

Comment: Yes!! thatz exactly what i wanna do..using jquery thankx

Comment: What have you tried? What code can you show us? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/gqTnX/5/)

You need to add this rss plugin (zrssfeed) in the head of your page to grab the feed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.komfrisk.dk/test/atom/jquery.zrssfeed.js"></script>
```

Next in your html, put this hidden div.

```
<div id="RSSview" style='display:none;'></div>
```

Finally, here is the script to load the first feed and find the image, then set it as the background

```
    function firstFeed(){
    $('#RSSview').rssfeed( 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/bingimages' , { limit: 1, offset: 0 });
    setTimeout(function(){
    var image = $('.rssMedia').find('a').attr('href');
    $('body').css({'background-image' : 'url("' + image + '")' });
    }, 2000);
}

firstFeed();
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the feed value that you want to display in a variable ( parse this fiddle and find the image that you want )

For example var imageUrl = "http://../../myImg.jpg"

Then use this:

```
$('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
```

Try my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8GBL/

Comment: Thanks...the problem is how can i parse the feed with jquery

Comment: I know to do that server side, with jquery i have a cross domain restriction.
I don't know if phonegap allow to you to work a web request to this feed and parsing the response.

A solution is to use a third part script/proxy. For example yql, this allow you to have a similar sql or linq on a XML/JSON/RSS. If you don't have a server side logic it can be usefull. Try My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8GBL/1/